# Facebook API - Access Token Delivers Inconsistent Information

Tags: php, facebook, api, get

In Facebook's API, the Graph Explorer(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) provides data on requested queries using Facebooks graph structure. When choosing the three fields,"ID, name, posts", the explorer returns all of the users posts of the user's wall, filtering out any activity the user has done anywhere else. It is strictly what is on the user's wall.

The problem here is that whenever I make a new application and test the applications data results using the Graph API explorer I always get similar, but extra information. The extra information is what's included in the user's, "Recent Activity", feed.

In the graph explorer if you look at the top there is a choice for an application, you can switch to the application you've made. Then when requesting an access token, you can select the, "read_stream", permission which allows an application to read a user's stream data i.e wall, news feed, etc.

[image: Using the Graph API Explorer]

[image: Using user-made application (Access_Token is blank for privacy purposes)]

The GET requests made by the Graph API Explorer application deliver different results then a custom made app using face book's developer API.

I've tried to locate the problems within the access tokens, but I've had no luck.

Comment: Probably the data related to posts is modified. A new  post or message  or comment may be added by the user in the mean time.

Comment: No, there's no modification, everything has been left to the native settings. The two requests are absolutely identical other than the access token. I just can't seem to figure out why it delivers different data.

Comment: How did you generate the access tokens? Through their debug tool itself? If so, can you confirm that the two sets of permissions are exactly the same when you generate them? 

I just tested this at my end and my data is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The access token is calculated based on the permissions you request.

Every time you change the permissions you are asking for, the access token will change.

I'm almost sure that Facebook Debugging App requests for some permissions you are not requesting, therefore you will not be able to replicate the results you get with their app in yours.